# curl 404 bad request

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-400

I am wrting a script to check whether site down or not and using following php code to

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user ');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
$return_val = curl_exec($ch);
$code =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
var_dump($code);
```

It works fine for some sites but some sites like as mentioned in CURLOPT_URL options returns 400 code

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html this url too doesn't work

I tried in my localhost as well as remote server but same thing happens

i also tried to add https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/Services/cacert.pem but still not working

What am i doing wrong ???

Comment: A 404 error is something actively sent by the requested server, not some transport problem or similar. Therefor, assumed that the urls you try are correct, it must be some active decision the server takes to answer with such error. It might for example be that this is an attempt to prevent page scrapers from reading content.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for a HEAD on a specific URL. The server then says that the page/resource doesn't exist by sending you the 404 response back.

This is not a client problem really, the server says the page doesn't exist. If you get a different result without [CURLOPT_NOBODY](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOBODY.html) set (which is sometimes the case) then you can in fact blame the server for not being properly HTTP compliant but that won't make anyone happier.

(Other answers may involve details such as [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html) and CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER but they are of course irrelevant here.)

Answer (score 0):

Remove white space `str_replace(" ", '%20', $url);`

Answer (score -2):

You need to add this `cURL` param as you are calling a HTTPs URL.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Also, you need to add this..

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

And comment of the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);` which is giving you the 404.

#### The working code..

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
$return_val = curl_exec($ch);
$code =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
var_dump($code);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
int 200
```